# How to take top 3 elements in each group using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the data in the source table.

[image: a]

And I want to get this kind of result in list using lambda expression and Entity Framework. I don't know how to do it. I need to get top 3 rows in for each CategoryId.

[image: a]

Probably using something like this:

```
context.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
       .Select(group => new { 
                                CategoryId = group.Key, 
                                NameId = group.Select(x => x.NameId), 
                                group.OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(3)
                            })
       .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: there should be a name for `group.OrderByDescending...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = context
    .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
    .SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(3))
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count)
    .ToListAsync();
```

If you want an anonymous type:

```
var list = context
    .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
    .SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(3))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.CategoryId, 
        x.NameId, 
        x.Count
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: does `.Take(3)` need `ToArry` or `ToList`? i'm worried later use will lose data if context disposed.

Comment: @LeiYang: No, you don't need to use `ToList` or `ToArray` after `Take(3)`. You want to execute the whole query in the database not in memory. `ToListAsync` already creates the list at the end.

Comment: Thank you Tim, it works. But, if I have only two columns CategoryId and NameId, how can I get the same result (first need define Count). Should I use many groupby()?

Comment: @Daniel: you want an anonymous type as result? Edited the answer

Comment: Probably, actually I do not not what anonymus type is. I tried you solution and it works, but before this I need to culculate Count value. And then .ToListAsync()

Comment: Yes, I read about anonymous type, it`s definately what I need

Comment: Tim, before getting this kind of "table" with CategoryId, NameId, DownloadId, I did 4 joins to get this, and now I need to get number of Downloads for each NameId, for each category. That is why I used kind of .GroupBy(x => new { x.CategoryId, x.NameId })
            .Select(group =>
                new { group.Key.CategoryId, group.Key.NameId, Count = group.Count() }), after it I have 3 columns CategoryId, NameId, Count. And now I need to get top 3 for each CategoryID.

Comment: After joins I have .GroupBy(x => new { x.CategoryId, x.NameId }) .Select(group => new { group.Key.CategoryId, group.Key.NameId, Count = group.Count() }), and after it i need to get top 3 for each CategoryID. I dont have a column Count. I just get it after query

Comment: @Daniel: why you can't prepend my query to yours?

Comment: Tim, Could you look at another my question, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71075006/using-count-and-groupby-to-take-top-n-elements-in-each-group-in-entity-frame