# Using Count() and GroupBy() to take top N elements in each group in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to get top 5 users according to downloads in each category and its UserId. But before that I should Count().

What I want to get as anonymous type:

| CategoryId | UserID | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 233 | 6000 |
| 1 | 123 | 500 |
| 1 | 137 | 400 |
| 1 | 258 | 300 |
| 1 | 777 | 200 |
| 2 | 231 | 7000 |
| 2 | 987 | 6000 |
| 2 | 656 | 3000 |
| 2 | 342 | 2000 |
| 2 | 1434 | 1000 |

```
var topDownloadUsers = await _userCategoryRepo
            .Join(
                _downloadRepo,
                x => x.UserId,
                p => p.UserId,
                (x, p) => new { x.CategoryID, x.UserId, DownloadId = p.Id })
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.CategoryID, x.UserId })
            .Select(x => new { x.Key.CategoryID, x.Key.UserId, Count = x.Count() })
            .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(5))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.CategoryID,
                x.UserId,
                x.Count
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

But I have an error: the LINQ expression could not be translated.

Comment: This is incredibly close to a Q that was asked yesterday.. Is it an assignment? It's so similar I wonder if it's a task set by some university..

Comment: Oh, wait... [It was you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065711/how-to-take-top-3-elements-in-each-group-using-entity-framework) 

Comment: No, It is not an assignment, it is for statistics of project.

Comment: How it ever compiles? `GroupBy(x => x.StandardId)` - `StandardId` is not accessible here.

Comment: Yes, its about CategoryId not StandartId. Fixed it in question.

Comment: Would you give sample data. It is not clear in your question why you ever have a need to do a join. In EF, provided you have a proper in your database (that in turn creates navigational properties via tools or by hand), you seldom need a join.

Comment: EF does not handle complex Linq. You might have to do it after you retrieve the value as list.

Comment: Is it impossible to do it, using one query?

Comment: Try switching to client side processing by putting `.AsEnumerable()` either after or before the second `GroupBy`.

Comment: @Daniel It's impossible to do it in one SQL query, which in-turn means it's impossible to do in a single Linq-to-Entities query It has to be 2 separate SQL queries because getting a single scalar count value is conceptually a separate query from getting rows of data of a particular schema type. The _good news_ is that `IQueryable<T>` is an immutable-builder, so you can reuse your query logic to get that scalar without needing to repeat yourself.

Comment: This should be possible in one sql query, but in my experience Entity Framework sometimes struggles to translate `GroupBy` expressions to sql. When it fails to translate something that you know you can do in SQL, you can just make a stored procedure and call that instead